# Upload image to two different folder locations using Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

This Code save image in only one folder. I want to upload the image at the same time in two different folders,
example 
folder-one
and 
folder-two

my controler

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [

       'photo_jpeg' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',


    ]);
}
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $photo_jpeg= time() . '.' . $data['photo_jpeg']->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $data['photo_jpeg']->move(base_path() . 'public/folder-one', $photo_jpeg);

return user::create([

        'photo_jpeg' => $photo_jpeg,


       ]);

}
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far to upload images in two different folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure these things. if you are going to update file on different location.

1. The folder must have the writtable permission.
2. Directory path should be defined absolute and point to correct location.

Now change verify the changes in code as follow.

```
$fileName = time() . '.' .$request->file('User_jpeg')->getClientOriginalExtension();

$storageLocation = '../../WEBSITE-FILE/TEAM/USER';  //it should be absolute path of storage location.

$request->file('User_jpeg')
        ->storeAs($storageLocation, $fileName);

$request->file('User_jpeg')
        ->storeAs($storageLocation . '/User_Profile_Image', $fileName);
```

**Edits:**

As per the requested current status, try this.

```
public function store(Request $request) { 
    $this->validate($request, [ 'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048', ]); $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->image->move(public_path('folder-a'), $input['image']);

    $fileSrc = public_path('folder-a') . $input['image'];
    $fileDest = public_path('folder-b') . $input['image'];

    \File::copy($fileSrc, $fileDest);

    Service::create($input); 

    return back()->with('success',' CREATED SUCCESSFULLY .'); 
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194110/discussion-on-answer-by-vikash-pathak-upload-image-to-two-different-folder-locat).

Comment: @vikash pathak your code worked  thank you , i am tried to pass two more folder but it only storing image in two folder without error how to solve this problem   
       $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
 $request->image->move(public_path('folder-a/'), $input['image']);
$fileSrc = public_path('folder-b/') . $input['image'];
$fileDest = public_path('folder-c/') . $input['image'];
$folderd = public_path('folder-d/') . $input['image'];
$foldere = public_path('folder-e/') . $input['image'];
     \File::copy($fileSrc, $fileDest, $folderd, $foldere);

Comment: You'll have to repeate this code no of times you are going to add folder.$fileDest = public_path('folder-b') . $input['image'];

    \File::copy($fileSrc, $fileDest); ...........make sure you have changed the `folder-b` to `folder-c`

Comment: Does this helped @RamuRamu?

Comment: @VikashPathak yes

Comment: Cool, hopefuly this time you'll not unmarked the solution :).

Comment: @Vikash Pathak  i added two more folder but it just passing  only two folder

Comment: // for folder-c
    $fileDest = public_path('folder-c') . $input['image'];
    \File::copy($fileSrc, $fileDest);

    // for folder-d
    $fileDest = public_path('folder-d') . $input['image'];
    \File::copy($fileSrc, $fileDest);

Comment: Just add these before the `Service::create($input); `

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){

        if($request->User_jpeg != ''){ //check file has selected 

            $file = $request->User_jpeg;

            $path = base_path('public/folder-one/');

            $filename = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $file->move($path, $filename); 

            \File::copy($path.$filename,base_path('public/folder-two/'.$filename));
        }

        user::create([
            'photo_jpeg' => $filename,
        ]);

    }
```

In route file (web.php):

```
Route::post('save-image', 'YourController@store');
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Now you can implement the above code.