# in laravel Upload image in two different folder at same time

Tags: laravel

> This Code save image in only one "folder-one". I want to upload the
>   image at the same time in two different folders, now it saving in folder-one
>
> example
>
> "folder-one"
>
> and
>
> "folder-two"

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
       'photo_jpeg' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    $photo_jpeg= time() . '.' . $data['photo_jpeg']->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $data['photo_jpeg']->move(base_path() . 'public/folder-one', $photo_jpeg);

    return user::create([
        'photo_jpeg' => $photo_jpeg,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: do you ned to save the uploaded image twice that is on ```folder-one``` and ```folder-two``` like the backup folder

Comment: yes to save twice in two different folder  on folder-one and folder-two

Comment: @Manojkiran.A.  yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload image to two different folder locations using Laravel 5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320944/upload-image-to-two-different-folder-locations-using-laravel-5-8)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run `move()` twice for the same file because as it name says, it moves the file, so on the second run, the original file won't exist anymore.

You must copy the file:

```
$uploadPath = public_path('folder-one/');
$file = $data['photo_jpeg'];
$photo_jpeg= time() . '.' .$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->move($uploadPath,$photo_jpeg);
\File::copy($uploadPath.$photo_jpeg,public_path('folder-two/').$photo_jpeg);
```

Comment: "showing error"                                                                                         bloge\public/folder-one/1558953247.jpeg: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: @RamuRamu see i edit the answer. and you have folders with named you want move in `public` directory

Comment: @RamuRamu I re-edit the answer i just put `$request` object in place of your `$data` array

Answer (score 0):

Use method `copy()` to make a copy of the file at the new destination.

```
$request->file('photo')->move($destination_path, $file_name); //original
copy($destination_path.$file_name, $new_path.$file_name); //backup
```