# How to store an image in two different folders in Laravel

Tags: laravel

The code below stores the image in only one folder. I would like to store the image in two different folders (Folder-A and Folder-B)

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Service; 

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()  
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('Folder-A/'), $input['image']);
        Service::create($input);

        return back()->with('success', 'CREATED SUCCESSFULLY.');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$request->image->move(public_path('Folder-A/'), $input['image']);` && `$request->image->move(public_path('Folder-B/'), $input['image']);`

Comment: @@ danish-khan                                                                                                  showing error    "The file "09-img.jpeg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error."

Comment: No Image was uploaded right?

Comment: yes not uploaded

Comment: did you `dd($request->image)` try this code.. what you are seeing?

Comment: i added ($request->image), but  same error

Comment: @@ danish-khan i added ($request->image), but same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in laravel Upload image in two different folder at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323662/in-laravel-upload-image-in-two-different-folder-at-same-time)

Comment: did you get image object in `dd($request->all());` and can you moved  in first location folder-A ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run `move()` twice for the same file because as it name says, it moves the file, so on the second run, the original file won't exist anymore.

You must copy the file:

```
$uploadPath = public_path('folder-one/');
$file = $request->file('image');
$photo_jpeg= time() . '.' .$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->move($uploadPath,$photo_jpeg);
\File::copy($uploadPath.$photo_jpeg,public_path('folder-two/').$photo_jpeg);
```

Comment: @RamuRamu I provided backend code not front end..I mean your html part