# laravel how to store image in 4 different folder at same time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

> my below code stores image 2 different at the same time but I am trying to
>   store image in 4 different folders at the same time, but it not storing 4
>   different folder it only passing image in 2 folders how to slow this
>   problem
>
> This code only Stores in Two Folder

```
public function store(Request $request)

    {

      $this->validate($request, [


          'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
          ]);


            $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->image->move(public_path('Folder-a/'), $input['image']);
            $folder1 = public_path('Folder-1/') . $input['image'];
            $folder2 = public_path(Folder-2/') . $input['image'];
            $folder3 = public_path('Folder-3/') . $input['image'];
            $folder4 = public_path(Folder-4/') . $input['image'];
            \File::copy($folder1, $folder2, $folder3, $folder4 );


        Service::create($input);

        return back()->with('success',' CREATED SUCCESSFULLY .');

    }
```

> @ Manojkiran.A you provided code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Service;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use saveFilesMultipleTimes;
class ServiceController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
$this->middleware('auth');
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, ['image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',]);
$mainFolderPath = public_path('Folder-a/');
$folder1 = public_path('Folder-1/');
$folder2 = public_path('Folder-2/');
$folder3 = public_path('Folder-3/'); 
$folder4 = public_path('Folder-4/'); 
$fileObject = $request->image; 
$filenamesWithPath = self::saveFilesMultipleTimes( $fileObject, $mainFolderPath, [$folder1, $folder2, 
$folder3, $folder4]);       
dd($filenamesWithPath);
function saveFilesMultipleTimes( \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile$requestFile, $mainFolderPath,$paths)
{    
$fileName = $requestFile->getClientOriginalName();    
$movedFile = $requestFile->move($mainFolderPath, $fileName);   
$currentFile = $movedFile->getPathName();     
foreach ( (array) $paths as $eachPath)
{
@mkdir( $eachPath);
@copy($movedFile->getPathName(), $eachPath . $fileName);
$dirctory[] = $eachPath.$fileName;
}
return $dirctory;
} 
Service::create($input);
return back()->with('success',' CREATED SUCCESSFULLY .');   
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload image to two different folder locations using Laravel 5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320944/upload-image-to-two-different-folder-locations-using-laravel-5-8)

Comment: @VikashPathak please solve this its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have tried many methods any finaly created the function

```
function saveFilesMultipleTimes( \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile$requestFile, $mainFolderPath,$paths)
{

    $fileName = $requestFile->getClientOriginalName();

    $movedFile = $requestFile->move($mainFolderPath, $fileName);

    $currentFile = $movedFile->getPathName();

    foreach ( (array) $paths as $eachPath) 
    {
        @mkdir( $eachPath);
        @copy($movedFile->getPathName(), $eachPath . $fileName);
        $dirctory[] = $eachPath.$fileName;
    }
    return $dirctory;
}
```

Copy and Paste it in your Controller

Now How to use it

```
$mainFolderPath = public_path('Folder-a/');
$folder1 = public_path('Folder-1/');
$folder2 = public_path('Folder-2/');
$folder3 = public_path('Folder-3/');
$folder4 = public_path('Folder-4/');


$fileObject = $request->image;
$filenamesWithPath = saveFilesMultipleTimes( $fileObject, $mainFolderPath, [$folder1, $folder2, $folder3, $folder4]);

dd($filenamesWithPath);
```

This dd Will give the **all filenames along with the path**

Hope its help

**UPDATED WITH CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Service;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',]);
        $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $mainFolderPath = public_path('Folder-a/');
        $folder1 = public_path('Folder-1/');
        $folder2 = public_path('Folder-2/');
        $folder3 = public_path('Folder-3/');
        $folder4 = public_path('Folder-4/');
        $fileObject = $request->image;
        $filenamesWithPath = self::saveFilesMultipleTimes($fileObject, $mainFolderPath, [$folder1, $folder2,
        $folder3, $folder4]);

        Service::create($input);  

        return back()->with('success', ' CREATED SUCCESSFULLY .');
    }

    public function saveFilesMultipleTimes(\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile$requestFile, $mainFolderPath, $paths)
    {
        $fileName = $requestFile->getClientOriginalName();
        $movedFile = $requestFile->move($mainFolderPath, $fileName);
        foreach ((array) $paths as $eachPath) {
            @mkdir($eachPath);
            @copy($movedFile->getPathName(), $eachPath . $fileName);
            $dirctory[] = $eachPath.$fileName;
        }
        return $dirctory;
    }

}
```

IF you are facing any issues kindly comment below

**AND IF THE FILE IS UPLOADING SUCCESSFULLY FOUR TIMES KINDLY MARK MY ANSWER AS ACCEPTED**

Comment: it showing error "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\saveFilesMultipleTimes()"

Comment: If You have Pasted ```saveFilesMultipleTimes```  in current controller then **FROM** ```$filenamesWithPath = saveFilesMultipleTimes( $fileObject, $mainFolderPath, [$folder1, $folder2, $folder3, $folder4]);``` **to** ```$filenamesWithPath = self::saveFilesMultipleTimes( $fileObject, $mainFolderPath, [$folder1, $folder2, $folder3, $folder4]);```

Comment: this will work perfectly i have tested it in my system

Comment: error "Method App\Http\Controllers\ServiceController::saveFilesMultipleTimes does not exist."

Comment: first copy my function  ```saveFilesMultipleTimes ``` and paste it in your controller

Comment: an error                                                                                              "Method App\Http\Controllers\ServiceController::saveFilesMultipleTimes does not exist."

Comment: please share the entire controller

Comment: i think you are new to php and laravel and you dont know how to use a function.

Comment: I have updated your controller kindly check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `\File::copy` method which has only two args - source and destination. So, you should just save your file and copy it separately as much as you need.

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_copy

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $folder1 = public_path('Folder-1/');

    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['image']; // path 1

    $request->image->move($folder1, $input['image']); // image saved in first folder

    $path2 = public_path('Folder-2/') . $input['image']; // path 2
    $path3 = public_path('Folder-3/') . $input['image']; // path 3
    $path4 = public_path('Folder-4/') . $input['image']; // path 4

    \File::copy($path1, $path2);
    \File::copy($path1, $path3);
    \File::copy($path1, $path4);

    Service::create($input);

    return back()->with('success',' CREATED SUCCESSFULLY .');
}
```

Comment: this code also passing image only folder-1 and folder-2

Comment: this code only passing image in folder-1 and folder-2

Comment: check folder permissions and laravel logfiles

Comment: i am running this project in localhost windows 10 pc folder permissions and laravel log files, i already checked but still same problem without any error

Comment: then check what returns each `File::copy()`